# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytorch_tabnet.augmentations' error

Tags: python, deep-learning

I pip installed pytorch_tabnet and when i try to import the ClassificationSMOTE class existing in the package augmentations i got this error: **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytorch_tabnet.augmentations'**
PS: i am working with the latest version of pytorch_tabnet 3.1.1 in google colab.

```
from pytorch_tabnet.augmentations import ClassificationSMOTE
```

Comment: You should try to reload to restart runtime.

Comment: I already did multiple times, but i get the same eroor each time

Comment: Maybe the latest pytorch_tabnet pip package is not up-to-date with the source code on Github.

Comment: i tried with earlier versions. None of them worked

Answer (score 3):

If the problem is that a module cannot be found, try to install the missing module into your running environment.

e.g.:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/dreamquark-ai/tabnet
```